# Mysterious disc space consumption on ubuntu server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, storage, docker

I have a server running on which many docker containers run and has capacity of around 400Gb and used storage is at 290GB and usage is increasing .Disc space is mounted on "/".

Here is the output of "df -h" running as a root:

```
tmpfs           6.0G   71M  6.0G   2% /run
/dev/xvda1      392G  295G   88G  78% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            394G  295G   84G  78% 
/var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/a8c1cc295d615ac7c24ae570f0e6a0872587b767f61d9261560a55a3b6c900ed
none            394G  295G   84G  78% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/ec3e8f485e970a92400d7d36d4ca1b18638a1d1ecbbe65162ba4666e75358ec6
```

Here is the output of  sudo du -h / | grep -P '^[0-9.]+G'

```
1.1G    /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/8d2bc80c9409a84a2b8cea5e35f55ad4d2c6b8f9937db3f23c988c09bd1c0e64
1.1G      /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/68f8312eb34763bcaf7833215adf9974c3e812b9cff6c668fd131cd0c4c2f1ff
1.9G /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/0e14789b512e25d900bf2140d68e0e4e82842be2645fdb3c4ffad402d1fb0260
1.2G    /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/1ca8b96421d90ea310cad9f2b41b116ade03f65fd61666018849dcab470bc54f
1.4G    /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/4e8bbe5c78cddb019f1393e97a3784f6a2083779c43ba05f5bff1daf4c9a6f13
28G /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt
22G /var/lib/docker/aufs/diff
49G /var/lib/docker/aufs
50G /var/lib/docker
50G /var/lib
50G
```

Question:

1.I am not sure on running **"df -h"** instead of only showing **"/"** mount why It is showing /var/lib/.... as a mount point too.

2.On running **"sudo du -h / | grep -P '^[0-9.]+G'
"** why it is only showing up the disc consumption upto 50G but not whole disc consumption  even when I am running **du** against a mount point shown by a **df**

Output of du -hs /var/lib/*

```
 8.0K   /var/lib/apparmor 
 127M   /var/lib/apt
 4.0K   /var/lib/aptitude
 50G    /var/lib/docker

 removed other entries because they were very small in size
```

Update:When I remove all the running containers then disc space utilization comes down to 7%.Which makes mw think that there is a rogue container which is filling up space because it takes almost 10hr to raise disc space to 80%.

What steps I can take to find out the rogue container?

mount :

```
 /dev/xvda1     ext4     412704840 312914896  82913940  80% /
 none           aufs     412704840 312914896  82913940  80% /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/a8c1cc295d615ac7c24ae570f0e6a0872587b767f61d9261560a55a3b6c900ed
```

Comment: Please show the output of `du -hs /var/lib/*`

Comment: @shodanshok I added the output

Comment: Whats the output of the `mount` command also what is the content of the `/etc/fstab`  It looks like the docker stuff is some sort of bind mount or loop back mount.

Comment: I think for #1, you actually want to use `sudo du -h --max-depth 1` (no grep afterwards). Otherwise, you get every subdirectory's size, too. Also, what file system is your root using? If it's something with snapshots, that could be taking up the space (especially with Docker!)

Comment: @James added the output

Comment: @lungj added the output

Comment: Protip: use `sudo du -sh /* | sort --human-numeric` to show a summary (`-sh`) of everything under / (`/*`), and sort it nicely. Just FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered on same [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/849790/my-disk-free-space-in-ubuntu-has-been-stolen/850351#850351) couple of time ago. Try to execute `lsof | grep delete`, to find deleted files that haven't seen by `du`, but use disk space. Also you could find process PID who lock this files.

Comment: @ Alexander Tolkachev  Thx Yeah that worked.Found out the PID using lsof command and from there  container  which was filling up tmp folder. BTW what is delete files which showed up in lsof represent?

Comment: @immrsteel see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18200701/lsof-shows-a-file-as-deleted-but-i-can-still-see-it-in-file-system)